# Email links do not open in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

I clicked on [a link](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/235226?noredirect=1) to a comment in my email and it prompted a list of apps to open link. All browsers (Chrome, Firefox and etc) are in the list, but not SE app.

Most apps that can open site specific links get prompted for that app to open  the link, but not Stack Exchange links for some reason.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Asus
- Device Model: ASUS_Z010D

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (WW_Phone-13.8.26.76-20161230)